# Rename fields in SubSonic select statement

Tags: subsonic

Is there a way to rename fields when executing a select statement in SubSonic? I am using the *ExecuteTypedList<MyClass>* method to fill my *List<MyClass>* object but the properties of MyClass are not all the same as the column names from the DB table. In SQL I can do *select col1 as 'FirstColumn', col2 as 'SecondColumn' from MyTable*, is there a way to do something similar in SubSonic?

Answer (score 1):

I believe Alias's are only available for aggregate columns.
You could just add properties of the same names as your columns to your class or a partial and map them to the properties you do use ala calculated field:

```
public class Songs
```

{

```
private string _songTitle;
public string SongTitle {
    get { return _songTitle; }
    set { _songTitle = value; }
}

public string SongName {
    get { return _songTitle; }
    set { _songTitle = value; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I had the same need the other day, and added the functionality to my local copy of SubSonic. I've just submitted it a patch for it attached to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/issues/detail?id=88). Applying the patch will let you write a query like

```
new Select(Table1.IdColumn.AliasAs("table1ID"),
Table2.IdColumn.AliasAs("table2ID"))
                .From(Table1.Schema)
                .InnerJoin(Table2.Table1IdColumn, Table1.IDColumn);
```